# PouchDB: .query() vs .find() vs .allDocs(), performance?

Tags: pouchdb

I'm new to PouchDB and don't have any setup already built to test the performance in retrieving data using pouchDB's `.query()` method, `.find()` method (in pouchdb-find plugin) nor `.allDocs()` with custom _id fields.

I'm trying to choose the approach to take and don't know which one is the best!

Has anyone tried the above methods? What's your experience with them? Which one was your favorite and why?

Does anyone have performance tests on them? Which one is the fastest? Which one is easier to implement and maintain? Which problems usually arise from them?

**Useful links:**

- https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database
- https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find
- https://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html

Thank you very much for your time!

Best regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 3):

[According to the docs](https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html#pouchdb-find), you should prefer `allDocs()` whenever possible:

> Avoid the query() API altogether if you can. You'd be amazed how much
>   you can do with just allDocs(). (In fact, under the hood, the query()
>   API is simply implemented on top of allDocs()!)